# Manipulating Date/Time Values with Google Apps Script

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script

I've been looking through Google App Script and having trouble finding info about the datetime object(?) they use. In my particular case, I'm trying to manipulate date-time values inputted by the user in a Google Spreadsheet. For example, we could return the time someone entered in cell B3 rounded to the nearest minute in a spreadsheet cell via some formula like *=MROUND(B3,"00:01:00")*. However, I don't know if there's an appropriate javascript/apps-script operation that does the same thing via the script editor?

I imagine maybe the trick involves finding some equivalent integer value to the datetime value (similar to the Date object in JS?) that we can then do a regular math operation on? Unfortunately, I only see the outputs in date-time format when I try to Logger.log the appropriate cell value(s)..

Comment: When you use getValue() from a script it will return a JavaScript date object if the cell contains a date or a time value. From there you can use any JS date method.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you requested. Checkout [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities).

```
function NEARESTMINUTE(value)
{
  if(time)
  {
     return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(value), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:00")
  }
  else
  {
    return 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```